# Is there an easy way to ask the TypeScript compiler to prefix everything to avoid collision with built-in JS classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there an easy way to ask the TypeScript compiler to prefix everything to avoid collision with built-in JS classes? I need a class with the name `Object` - it represents a Firebase Storage Object:

```js
export default class Object {
  // etc
}
```

However, when I try to run the compiled code, I see the error: `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Object' before initialization`. That's mainly because the compiled file uses the [built-in Object class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// compiled js code below.
```

Is there a way to avoid the collision? Maybe a compiler flag. I'd like to avoid using Webpack right now if possible.

Comment: why not just rename the `Object` to something else like `FirebaseStorageObject`?

Comment: Redundancy I guess

Comment: If "redundancy" is really the only reason, I'd suggest you rethink the decision. Sharing variable name with a built-in global scope name will only confuse your future self and your teammates down the line, especially when you want to use built-in functions like `Object.assign`.

Comment: You could wrap your types/classes in a namespace, which gets emitted as an object (I think). It seems like it meets the "easy" criteria.